# React app mysteriously has touchscreen functionality

Tags: reactjs, touch

I've recently created a site for a friends business using create-react-app.
I completed the website layout and tested it on my mobile phone to find that touch events **were** registering and working properly (on `<NavLink>` elements), despite not having written touch events at all myself.

I haven't installed any packages for touch-events.

I'm working on another project and not having the same result; They're set up very similarly, I've tried changing the project that has **no** touch functionality to match the one that does.

Has anyone encountered this before that could shed some light on why this is happening?

Comment: The mobile browser emulates mouse events, why would it not work?

Comment: Seems like you've broken the default behaviour on the other website somehow